# If $P(A)=0.4$, $P(B)=0.6$, and $P(A\cap B) = 0.7$, what is $P(A\cup B)$?

Tags: probability

$P(A) = 0.4$

$P(B) = 0.6$

$P(A \cap B) = 0.7$

What is $P(A \cup B)$?

I can work out that $P(A \cup B) = 0.3$ using probability formulas, but it makes no sense to me. I'm trying to think of the problem as a Venn diagram. How can it be that the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is more than $A$ and $B$ themselves? Also, how is it that the union of $A$ and $B$ is less than either $A$ or $B$? Is the math being wonky here?

Comment: How can $P(A\cap B)$ can be more then $P(A)$ or $P(B)$? It must be less than or equal to these probabilities.

Comment: It must have been a typo.  By definition of a probability measure, one must have that if $E\subseteq F$ then $P(E)\leq P(F)$.  Noting that $A\cap B\subseteq A$ we should have had $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$ as well.  Most likely, the question author made a mistake and meant to write that $P(A\cup B)=0.7$ or that $P(A\cap B)=0.3$ and asked you to find the missing information.

Answer (score 2):

The question is illposed. It must be the case that
$$
P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)
$$
and
$$
P(A\cap B)\leq P(B)
$$